# Printing a struct in a struct in a linked list

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct stockItem {
    char *componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems;
    int price;
} stockItem;

// declaration
stockItem *stockItem_new(char *componentType, char *stockCode, int numOfItems, int price);
```

And a struct like this to store many stock items ( linked list )

```
typedef struct inventory {
    struct stockItem item;
    struct inventory *next;
}inventory;
```

These are both in different header file.

I have created the linked list, I want to print off certain bits of data, such:

```
void outputData(){

    // This temporarily takes the location of the structs in the
    // linked list as we cycle through them to the end

    struct inventory *myInv = pFirstNode;

    printf("Current Inventory\n\n");

    // Until the ptr reaches a value of NULL for next we'll
    // keep printing out values

    while(myInv != NULL){
        // HERE IS MY PROBLEM HOW DO I PRINT OFF THE COMPONENTTYPE FROM THIS
        printf("%s\n\n", myInv->item->compnentType);
        // Switch to the next struct in the list
        myInv = myInv->next;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
stockItem *stockItem_new(char *componentType, char *stockCode, int numOfItems, int price){
   // creates a new duration for the song
   stockItem *item = (stockItem*)malloc(sizeof(stockItem));

   // assigns the attributes
   item->componentType   = componentType;
   item->stockCode = stockCode;
   item->numOfItems = numOfItems;
   item->price = price;
   // returns it
   return item;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code of `stockItem_new`

Comment: Certaininly @AlterMann

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C, also why do you have a `stockItem_new` (which returns a pointer) if you don't keep a pointer in the `inventory`? (with that declaration, it would be `item.compnentType` since `item` is not a pointer to `stockItem`).

Comment: I made the stockItem before the inventory so I guess I wasn't foward thinking. What do you mean don't cast the result of malloc in c? @crashmstr

Comment: What does the compiler tell you when you try to compile the code in the question? The `myInv->item->componentType` is a `char`, but you need a `char *` to print with `%s`, so simple changing it to `myInv->item.componentType` could just do it.

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: This is what I get @HonzaRemeš Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Ý²`

Comment: @session_start: That is maybe what your program prints. What I am asking is: "What messages do you get when compiling the code?"

Comment: You probably need to change `inventory` to be a `struct stockItem *` to work with your `stockItem_new` (but you *don't* show us enough code to know for certain).

Comment: @crashmstr perfect mate, changed it to struct stockItem * and i can access with this code printf("%s\n\n", myInv->item->componentType); Make an answer and and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see the rest of the code, but since you have `stockItem_new` returning a pointer, then this is wrong:

```
typedef struct inventory {
    struct stockItem item; ///missing *!
    struct inventory *next;
} inventory;
```

Instead, we need to declare it as:

```
typedef struct inventory {
    struct stockItem *item;
    struct inventory *next;
} inventory;
```

Then you can assign to the `item` with your `stockItem_new` function and your `outputData` will work as you expect.

**Update:**
In your `stockItem_new`, you are not making a copy of the contents of `componentType`, but just pointing to the same value. You either need to allocate a new buffer each time and pass into `stockItem_new` or take care of that with `strdup`

```
item->componentType = strdup(componentType);
```

This will allocate enough memory and copy the contents of `componentType`. You would need to do this for any strings you will be keeping in your struct (since only the address is copied!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, another quick question. I'm printing out the data and for some reason I am getting the same stock code for each item in the inventory but the ints are working fine ( price, count ) any ideas? I'm guessing it has something to do with the pointers

Comment: You are pointing to the same buffer each time. In your `stockItem_new` you could use [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to allocate new storage with a copy of the string.

Comment: Am I not doing that with stockItem *item = malloc(sizeof(stockItem));

Comment: That is creating an "empty" item. When you do this `item->componentType   = componentType;`, you point to the same thing as `componentType`, and it that later changes (due to reading a file, etc.), then they *all* change.

Comment: So I'd need to use strdup for all of them ?

Comment: @session_start I've updated my answer. You only need to do that with strings (since they are pointers).

Comment: Ahh thats brilliant, could this be done a different way? by dereferencing?

Comment: @session_start You might want to read up on string handling and learn more about pointers. If you had a pointer to an `int`, you would dereference it to get the value. Since strings are arrays of values, you don't work with them in the same way.

Comment: Absolutely I'll have a read into it, thank you again. Say if I were to have a file which brings up all the sales ( date, stock code, amount)  is it possible to have a function call in a struct so I can have the StockItem within the sales struct if that makes sense?